# ItemsControl with multiple DataTemplates for a viewmodel

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, viewmodel

is it possible to bind an itemscontrol with canvas as template to multiple DataTemplates?

I have 2 collections and depending on the type I would like to display a different control on my canvas.

I am not sure but I could think about a Viewmodel which has 2 ObservableCollections. For example if I would have "Shapes" and "connections" and I would like to display them both on the canvas? In case of a diagraming scenario...

I would like to do this in the mvvm manner and I am not sure if the multiple DataTemplate approach is correct but this came to my mind. 
But I am still having problems to get the binding straight in my head. If I set the DataContext to the ViewModel for me it seems not possible to bind 2 collections to the items control... =(
I am also open for other ideas, too....

Is this possible? And if so, how would the binding look like an

Comment: Do you need it **BOTH** for WPF and Silverlight?

Comment: both would be nice long term... but first WPF would be great...

Comment: DataTemplateSelector will work for both `WPF` and `Silverlight`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can create multiple `ObservableCollections` and then bind your `ItemsSource` to a [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) which joins those collections.

Then in your XAML you can create different `DataTemplates` for the respective types using the `DataType` property which like styles gets automatically applied if it is placed in the resources. (You can also create the composite in XAML which is shown on MSDN, if the `CollectionContainers` should be bound that is [a bit more difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446923/546730) though)

Example code:

```cs
ObservableCollection<Employee> data1 = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(new Employee[]
{
    new Employee("Hans", "Programmer"),
    new Employee("Elister", "Programmer"),
    new Employee("Steve", "GUI Designer"),
    new Employee("Stefan", "GUI Designer"),
    new Employee("Joe", "Coffee Getter"),
    new Employee("Julien", "Programmer"),
});
ObservableCollection<Machine> data2 = new ObservableCollection<Machine>(new Machine[]
{
    new Machine("E12", "GreedCorp"),
    new Machine("E11", "GreedCorp"),
    new Machine("F1-MII", "CommerceComp"),
    new Machine("F2-E5", "CommerceComp")
});
CompositeCollection coll = new CompositeCollection();
coll.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = data1 });
coll.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = data2 });
Data = coll;
```

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Employee}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" ("/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Occupation}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=")"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Machine}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Manufacturer}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here i use a different panel but it should be the same for a canvas.

Comment: Unfortunately, the COmpositeCollection isn't available for UWP Framework.

Comment: If Employee and Machine class are both inherit from the same class X, CompositeCollection is not needed and one ObservableCollection of X is enough.

Comment: @Viliam: Sure, but that is one major assumption which will not hold in many cases.

Answer (score 5):

You could have `ObservableCollection<object>` in your ViewModel and bind the ItemsControl's Source to this collection.

Then, to get a different look for different types of data, you could two DataTemplates without x:Key, but with properly set DataType in your Resources. The ItemsControl will then automatically select the appropriate DataTemplate for your item.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Data template selector: [here](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2009/03/16/Dynamic-Data-Forms-for-Silverlight-with-a-Data-Template-Selector-Control.aspx) or
[here](http://www.st-lange.net/post/DataTemplate-Selector-fuer-Silverlight.aspx).

Answer (score -6):

Another option with less code behind would be to define two ListBoxes, each with their own templates and bound to their own collections.  Define them each in the same physical space and just control which one is visible based on your state.  You could even do this with the Visual State Manager and custom states.