# Applying different styles to ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I'm using a `CompositeCollection` to host objects I want to display in a `ItemsControl` control, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473001/itemscontrol-with-multiple-datatemplats-for-a-viewmodel) solution to implement using different DataTemplates for the different objects, however I want to apply for each of the types in my collection a different style. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mapNamespace:MapObject}">
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding MapObjLocation.X}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding MapObjLocation.Y}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Rectangle Fill="#00000000" Height="10" Width="10" Stroke="Red">
                    <Rectangle.ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="X:  "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MapObjLocation.X}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Y: " />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MapObjLocation.Y}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Rectangle.ToolTip>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ReferenceMapRectangle}">
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Rectangle Height="{Binding Height, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="{Binding Width, Mode=TwoWay}" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="6"
                           Canvas.Top="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay}" Canvas.Left="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}" >

                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
```

The actual result from running this is that the MapObjects will be shown in the correct location on the `Canvas`, but the `ReferenceMapRectangle` object will stay fixed in (0,0) on the canvas and will never move (the width / height does update, though)

Does anyone have a clue why this could happen? I tried using `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` but it only supports one style, and not multiple styles.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be a binding issue instead of a style issue? Check your debug output window.

Comment: Don't think so since my Width / Height bind correctly. I think that the Style in the DataTemplate.Resources is not accessible. The code only looks at the ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Item in an `ItemsControl` is wrapped in a `<ContentPresenter>` tag, so applying your positioning on your actual DataItem will do nothing.

You can use `ItemContainerStyle` to apply the positioning on the `ContentPresenter` tag instead of your DataItem tag

For example, here is how your controls get rendered if you apply positioning to your `DataItem`:

```
<Canvas>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <DataItem Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <DataItem Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50" />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <DataItem Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="50" />
    </ContentPresenter>
</Canvas>
```

And here is how your controls would get rendered if you apply positioning in the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Canvas>
    <ContentPresenter Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50">
        <DataItem />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50">
        <DataItem />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="50">
        <DataItem />
    </ContentPresenter>
</Canvas>
```

See [this blog entry of mine](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) for another example