# Binding dynamically generated textblock WPF MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

I am using MVVMM Light WPF and I want to do the following: Generate textboxes dynamically and bind them to a property of a class.

I already have the following but it doesn't show up in my view when running the application.

This is my collection:

```
        private ObservableCollection<Border> _controllekes;
    public ObservableCollection<Border> Controllekes
    {
        get { return _controllekes; }
        set
        {
            _controllekes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Controllekes");
        }
    }
```

This it my xaml:

```
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Controllekes}">

                    </ItemsControl>
```

This is a part where I fill the itemsource "Controllekes":

```
                Controllekes = new ObservableCollection<Border>();
            Border border = new Border();
            border.BorderThickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(5);
            border.BorderBrush = Brushes.AliceBlue;
            border.Padding = new System.Windows.Thickness(5);
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Background = Brushes.Red;
            Binding nameTextBinding = new Binding("Controllekes");
            nameTextBinding.Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath(this.Dossier.Omschrijving);
            nameTextBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            //nameTextBinding.Source = this.Dossier.Omschrijving;
            tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, nameTextBinding);
            border.Child = tb;
            this.Controllekes.Add(border);
```

What it does it creates a border with in this border a textblock where the binding should happen. I whish to bind the property this.Dossier.Omschrijving (Dossier is the class). If I just enter a string in the textbox it works.

In runtime the border gets generated but the textblock remains empty. The object Dossier.Omschrijving contains information.

What do I do wrong?

**EDIT**:

safe put me in the right direction and the answer of [ItemsControl with multiple DataTemplates for a viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473001/itemscontrol-with-multiple-datatemplats-for-a-viewmodel) made me finish the job :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

through all that and use ItemTemplate

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding yourboolProperty}"/>
                <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="{Binding yourStringProperty}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and set `ic`'s ItemsSource to List

Comment: The thing is that the itemscontrol will be filled with textboxes, textblocks, checkboxes and radiobuttons. So I cannot do it like that

Comment: put all you want in ItemTemplate and bind only properties not controls

Comment: I'm sorry..could you give me an example?

Comment: k..and how to fill the list with for example 2 textboxes created in code?

Comment: first i suppose to you reading more about ItemTemplate and DataTemplate in general.

Comment: you can fill it by set list with two items, so the itemsControl fill its list with the number of item that you support, and it dynamically view each item with the shape of your ItemTemplate that you declare

Comment: K thanks. I accept your answer cause I can see the solution thanks to your advice.

Comment: In addition I also managed to get it working thanks to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473001/itemscontrol-with-multiple-datatemplats-for-a-viewmodel