# Multiple format types listview in C# and XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I am creating a messaging application with a listview that displays message objects.

When a new user joins, I want to add (for example) "John joined" but I want it to be formatted differently than a message.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this scenario, you can implement the [ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) of the `ListView`.

For example, create a class inherit from `DataTemplateSelector` first like this:

```
public class MessageDataTemplateSelecotr : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate NormalTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate JoinedTemplate { get; set; }
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var message = item as MessageModel;
        if (message.MessageType.ToString() == "Normal")
            return NormalTemplate;
        else
            return JoinedTemplate;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this selector for example like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalMessageTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Blue"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="JoinedMessageTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" FontSize="15" Foreground="Red"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:MessageDataTemplateSelecotr x:Key="MessageDataTemplateSelecotr" 
                                       NormalTemplate="{StaticResource NormalMessageTemplate}" 
                                       JoinedTemplate="{StaticResource JoinedMessageTemplate}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MessageDataTemplateSelecotr}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind listViewCollection}"/>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind just add data into the `listViewCollection` like this:

```
ObservableCollection<MessageModel> listViewCollection = new ObservableCollection<MessageModel>();
private enum _MessageType
{
    Normal,
    Joined
}
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    listViewCollection.Add(new MessageModel { Message = "hello world!", MessageType = _MessageType.Normal });
    listViewCollection.Add(new MessageModel { Message = "John joined", MessageType = _MessageType.Joined });
}
```

And my `MessageModel` class is like this:

```
public class MessageModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Enum MessageType { get; set; }
}
```

The rendering image of this `ListView` is here:
[image]

Comment: In the line with <local:MessageDataTemplateSelector I get green underlines under NormalTemplate and JoinedTemplate saying that the member is not recognized of accessible, but everything else is exactly the same as what you wrote and works. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @Jenny, as I know, it's a known issue, just ignore it will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the accepted answer on this question, [ItemsControl with multiple DataTemplates for a viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473001/itemscontrol-with-multiple-datatemplates-for-a-viewmodel)

You could use a CompositionCollection with two Datatemplates defined in your listview.  One datatemple for normal messages, one for join messages.

Comment: No, OP asked a question about UWP app, and you provided a method about WPF app. Please notice the tag of the question.