# UWP/XAML How to Change Individual Items Within a Data Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Say for example I data bind a collection of Book objects to a ListView.  The ListView contains a TextBlock of "Book.Title" so the UI will show a list of book titles in the collection.  But what if, for certain individual Books in the collection, the boolean property "Book.IsCheckedOut" is true, and I want those specific books to be displayed in boldface (or italic or a different color or whatever.)  How can specific elements in a bound collection have unique properties assigned to them?

Comment: What did you try so far ? Share some code to get help on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a converter, like this one:

```
public class BoolToFontWeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var currentValue = (bool);
        return currentValue ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then bind it in the xaml like this:

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="{Binding IsCheckedOut, Converter={StaticResource BoolToFontWeightConverter}}" />
```

and you'll need to add it as a resource in the page where it's used, or in the app xaml

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is implementing the [ItemTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) of your `ListView`, you can check my answer in another question: [Multiple format types listview in C# and XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276321/multiple-format-types-listview-in-c-sharp-and-xaml/38280290#38280290).

To implement this, you need:

1. Design two `DataTemplate` for your `ListView`, one in boldface, the other one not.
2. Implement the class for `DataTemplateSelector`.
3. Using this `DataTemplateSelector` in your `ListView`.
4. Add data to your collection and set this collection as `ItemsSource` of your `ListView`.